# Big O notation (on both sides)

Tags: algorithm

I need step-by-step prove that: **7 + O(n) = O(n)**

I have no idea how to do it when there are Big O on both sides.

I think I understand concept of big O notation but why is there Big O on both sides?

Comment: Strictly speaking the above does not make much sense. *O* is a function that maps a function to a set of functions. You can not add `7` to a set of functions. You likely should prove that *O(n+7) = O(n)*. You thus need to proof that each function in the set of *O(n+7)* is in the set of *O(n)* and vice versa.

Comment: What you need to prove is that if f(n) is O(n) then f(n)+7 is also O(n).

Comment: And how can I prove that O(n) = O(n+7)?

Comment: By using the definition of big O

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Since you were able to understand what it was the OP needs to prove, I would say that shows it does make sense; it's just not written in a formal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the formal definition of big O notation:

`f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n.` ([big-O notation](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html)).

[image]

If your complexity is, for example, `O(n^2)`, then you can guarantee that there is some value of n (greater than k) after which `f(n)` in no case will exceed `c g(n)`.

Let's try to prove `q(n) = f(n) + 7` is `O(n)`, where `f(n)` is `O(n)`:

1. From the definition, there exists a function `f(n)` such that `f(n) ≤ c n` for all `n ≥ k`.
2. Now, we want to prove `q(n)` is `O(n)`. We prove this by contradiction. We say if `q(n)` is not `O(n)`, there exist no `k'` and `c'` such that `q(n) ≤ c' n` for all `n ≥ k'`  **(original assumption)**. Now,

`q(n) = f(n) + 7 ≤ c n + 7` for all `n ≥ k`  ---- (1).

From the definition, `c > 0` and `k > 0`. Now, `(c + 1) n ≥ c n + 7` for all `n ≥ max(k, 7)`, `c > 0`

=> `(c + 1) n ≥ f(n) + 7` for all `n ≥ max(k, 7)`, `c > 0` (From eqn (1))

=> `(c + 1) n ≥ q(n)` for all `n ≥ max(k, 7)`, `c > 0` ----(2)

Substituting `c' = c + 1` and `k' = max(k, 7)` in the above equation, we quickly find a contradiction:

`c' n ≥ q(n)` for all `n ≥ k'` (written as **original assumption** in step 2)

This is a contradiction in that our original assumption that no such values of `c'` and `k'` exist is violated. Hence, `O(n) + 7` is `O(n)`.

This completes your proof. Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** It is also sufficient to show that some `k'` and `c'` exist for our proof to work. We could simply skip the contradiction part.

Comment: This is an "absurd absurdum" - you suppose the theorem is false, then prove it is true, reaching a contradiction in order to show that the initial assumption (that the theorem is false) is false. You might as well just do the middle part of proving the theorem is true.

Comment: By the way, you need to let `k' = max(k, 7)` for this to work; `k' = 7` doesn't follow because the original `k` that works for the function `f` might be larger than 7.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion into improving my answer, @kaya3. However, I never supposed the theorem is false, rather used it as a premise to draw an initial set of assumptions, which could later be proved wrong using contradiction.

Comment: *"We say if q(n) is not O(n), there exist no k' and c' such that ..."* You assume q(n) is not in O(n), then prove it is in O(n), in order to reach a contradiction, hence concluding that it's not not in O(n). The middle part of your proof, which shows q(n) is in O(n), is all you need.

Comment: If it were, indeed, true that `q(n)` is not in `O(n)`, there would be no values `k'` and `c'` such that `f(n) ≤ c' n, n ≥ k'`. Like any other proof by contradiction, I supposed it is true, then gave an argument why the values `c'` and `k'` exist.

Comment: You showed they exist by exhibiting c' and k' which satisfy the conditions, hence proving that q is in O(n). You could simply exhibit the same c', k' and conclude "therefore, q is in O(n)" without setting up a contradiction. It makes the proof simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This use of notation does not accord with the formal definition of big O notation, so it's not clear what level of formality the proof needs to be. Also, since the notation is not formal, it takes some interpretation to decide what actually needs to be proved.

I interpret this as asking for a proof that, given any function which is in O(*n*), if you add 7 to all of the values of that function, then the new function is also in O(*n*). More formally, for all *f* in O(*n*), the function *g*(*n*) = *f*(*n*) + 7 is also in O(*n*).

This can be proved straightforwardly from the definition:

1. We need to show that, for every *f* in O(*n*), the function *g*(*n*) = *f*(*n*) + 7 is also in O(*n*).
2. Since *f* is in O(*n*), there exist constants *c* and *N* such that for all *n* >= *N*, the value of *f*(*n*) <= *cN*.
3. It follows that *g*(*n*) = *f*(*n*) + 7 <= *cN* + 7 <= (*c* + 7)*N* for all *n* >= *N*, so long as *N* >= 1.

So given constants *c* and *N* proving *f* is in O(*n*), the constants (*c* + 7) and max(*N*, 1) work for proving that *g* is in O(*n*). QED.

Comment: As an aside, the constants (*c* + 1) and max(*N*, 7) also work fine. When proving these things, you just need to choose constants that are "big enough" for the proof to work.

Answer (score 1):

The statement *7 + O(n) = O(n)* does not make much sense. *O : (ℕ → ℕ) → P(ℕ → ℕ)* is a function that maps a function to a set of functions. You can not add seven to a *set* of functions. You could "include" it, but this is likely not what the expression aims to do.

What you likely need to do is proof that *O(n+7) = O(n)*. You can proof that two sets are equal by proving that each element in the first set is a member of the second set, and each element in the second set is a member of the first set.

The set of functions that arises from *O(n)* is defined as each function *g*, such that for this *g* there exists an *n<sub>0</sub>* and a value *k > 0*, such that for all *n∈ℕ* with *n > n<sub>0</sub>*, it holds that *g(n)≤k×n*. You thus need to proof that all these functions are a member of the set that arises from *O(n+7)*, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Big O notation is applicable for asymptotically large value of n. Therefore constants make no change to the Big O notations.

Comment: This is not a proof, this is more "hand-waving": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-waving

Answer (score -1):

O(n)+constant = O(n) constant doesn't make much difference in this scenario so we can omit constant.

Comment: What deep mathematical proof.